# Postgresql constraint violated at restore

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a problem with a constraint that is being violated by some rows when restoring my DB, but has never been violated at usage.

I have 3 tables :

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "as" (
  "id" bigserial NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bs" (
  "id" bigserial NOT NULL,
  "some_id" bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  FOREIGN KEY ("some_id") REFERENCES "some_table" ("id") 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "as_bs" (
    "a_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "b_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("a_id", "b_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("a_id") REFERENCES "as" ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("b_id") REFERENCES "bs" ("id")
);
```

`some_table` here is another table, which I think is not relevant for this problem.

Now what I want is to have a unicity constraint between `as.id` and `bs.some_id` through the relation table `as_bs`. E.g:

```sql
INSERT INTO some_table (id) VALUES(1),(2);
INSERT INTO "as" (id) VALUES(1),(2);
INSERT INTO bs (id,some_id) VALUES(1,1),(2,1);
INSERT INTO as_bs (a_id,b_id) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO as_bs (a_id,b_id) VALUES(1,2); -- <<-- Offending row !!!
```

(Thanks @wildplasser for formatting)

This brings me to the following constraint:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_a_b_some_table_unicity(a_id bigint, b_id bigint)
RETURNS boolean AS
$body$
    BEGIN
        return (SELECT(COUNT(*) = 0)
        FROM as_bs ab
        JOIN bs o1 ON o1.id = ab.b_id
        JOIN bs o2 ON o2.some_id = o1.some_id
        WHERE ab.a_id = $1 AND o2.id = $2);
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE as_bs ADD CONSTRAINT check_a_b_some_table_unicity CHECK (check_a_b_some_table_unicity(a_id, b_id));
```

Then my program has lived its life, but when I want to restore a recent backup I got an error because of this constraint.

In my backup, I removed the constraint function and the check and I can restore my backup with no problem. Of course then if I'm trying to reapply the check, I got:

```sql
ERROR:  check constraint "check_a_b_some_table_unicity" is violated by some row
```

So I went to the idea of finding what rows are faulty.

To do that, I joined `as` and `bs` to `as_bs` and grouped by the unicity group `(a_id, b_id, some_id)`:

```sql
SELECT a_id, b_id, bs.some_id, COUNT(*) occurrences FROM as_bs
JOIN bs ON as_bs.b_id = bs.id
JOIN as ON as_bs.a_id = as.id
GROUP BY a_id, b_id, bs.some_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

and I got the surprise that it did not return any row...

Now I'm just wondering what's the problem between

- My constraint is wrong for what I want to do
- My unicity check just above does not check what I want to check

and anyway, I'm also wondering how a constraint that could be registered once can't be restored now because it was violated.

Comment: `bs.some_id` is functionally dependant on `bs.id`, so your constraint is redundant.

Comment: In your function you are not checking if `o1.id <> o2.id` so a row is detected as its own duplicate. The verification query is also logically different from your function. [also: use (NOT) EXISTS() instead of count()] And please state in your question the actual **goal** of your constraint. As it is, it seems nonsensical.

Comment: Please try to invent some data to illustrate the purpose of your constraint, and add it to your question. Data that **is** unique on `(a_id, b_id)`, but **not unique** on `(a_id, b_id, some_id)`

Comment: @wildplasser I just edited to add an example of what must be forbidden. You were right, I was not clear on what I wanted to constrain.

Comment: Please add your test data as *data* (e.g. : VALUES...) , not as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "as_bs" (
    "a_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "b_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("a_id", "b_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("a_id") REFERENCES "as" ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("b_id") REFERENCES "bs" ("id")
);
```

---

In your current schema, `(as_bs.a_id, as_bs.b_id)` is unique
Adding dependant columns from `as` or `bs` won't make it **more** unique.

---

UPDATE:

---

```
\i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "as" (
  "id" bigserial NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "some_table" (
  "id" bigserial NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bs" (
  "id" bigserial NOT NULL,
  "some_id" bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("some_id") REFERENCES "some_table" ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "as_bs" (
    "a_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "b_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("a_id", "b_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("a_id") REFERENCES "as" ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("b_id") REFERENCES "bs" ("id")
);

INSERT INTO some_table (id) VALUES(1),(2);
INSERT INTO "as" (id) VALUES(1),(2);
INSERT INTO bs (id,some_id) VALUES(1,1),(2,1);
INSERT INTO as_bs (a_id,b_id) VALUES(1,1);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_a_b_some_table_unicity(a_id bigint, b_id bigint)
RETURNS boolean AS
$body$
    BEGIN
      return NOT EXISTS ( -- Prefer NOT EXISTS to COUNT(*) < 1
        SELECT *
        FROM as_bs ab
        JOIN bs o1 ON o1.id = ab.b_id
        JOIN bs o2 ON o2.some_id = o1.some_id AND o2.id <> o1.id
        WHERE ab.a_id = $1 AND o2.id = $2
        );
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE as_bs ADD CONSTRAINT check_a_b_some_table_unicity CHECK (check_a_b_some_table_unicity(a_id, b_id));

INSERT INTO as_bs (a_id,b_id) VALUES(1,2); -- <<-- Offending row !!!
```

---

Output:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
INSERT 0 2
INSERT 0 2
INSERT 0 1
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  new row for relation "as_bs" violates check constraint "check_a_b_some_table_unicity"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2).
```

Comment: You are right, I did not explain right the constraint I wanted to have. Indeed (a_id, b_id) are unique but the unicity I'm looking for is (a_id, bs.some_id) through relation as_bs.

Comment: An assignment-problem. Comes close to 4NF... (join-dependency?) Maybe move `some_id` to the as_bs table and have **two** unique constrants on (a_id, b_id) and (a_id, some_id)

Comment: Indeed that seems not normal that the constraint fails while adding it whereas there is only one row in as_bs... so there definitely is a problem in my syntax. I'll dig this way. Unfortunately I can't add some_id to as_bs (I'd need one more join each time accessing bs, which is not acceptable in my application).

Comment: Did you notice that my function is different? (and behaves as required?)

Comment: Indeed sorry I thought it fail on adding the constraint! I'll definitely try that. I didn't even know the <> operator (quite an SQL newbie...)

Comment: You could probably rewite it using `x1.a_id <> x2.a_id`, but that might be implied. Too tired now ...

Comment: This seems to work anyway, I could add the constraint to the table, which I couldn't do with my broken version. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you dump&restore your database but this seems to be connected to the fact that function refers to records that may not exist yet when loading some data from other tables.

Consider `--disable-triggers` option if you are using pg_restore

If you are simply loading sql - I would assume that all of your `CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` should be in the end of sql file - this should work out of the box if you are using `pg_dump` and later `psql... database < dump.sql`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the fact that even after restore I can't add my constraint again makes me think there is a real problem with the constraint more than in the dump/restore, even if the constraint is at the end.